# How to detect scroll event when scrolling on a position fixed element

Tags: vue.js, scroll, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

My project is built on **nuxt.js** with **vue composition api**

So, my scroll event is not firing because my container has `overflow:hidden`. Is there any way that I can have the scroll event fire up even when overflow is hidden?

HTML

```
<template>
  <div id="test">
    <full-page ref="fullpage" :options="options" id="fullpage">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="details">Details</div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="your-name"/>
      </form>
    </full-page>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
function handleScroll(e: any) {
  console.log('scrolled')
}
onMounted(() => {
  const t = = document.getElementById('test')
  t!.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
}
```

The objective is to have the form to only show up with some animation whenever I scroll in this `#test` div, while having the rest of the elements fixed.
But for now I'm outputting a console log just to check if it works.

Comment: What is your HTML and CSS code? Very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve without that or an example snippet that replicates it

Comment: Whats your CSS? Is this component part of a larger view (part of a page with other elements) or is it 'full screen'?

Comment: It is full screen, I am using fullpage.js for it. Imagine there is only one section in this demo https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1 . So scrolling will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat complicated to achieve as you request, by using the `overflow: hidden` the scroll ability is lost and thus not possible as-is.

To capture the scroll event on an overflow hidden element, you'll have to re-create the scroll event yourself by adding an event listener to the `wheel` (mouse) instead. Note that browser support may be inconsistent.
Also note that this won't account for up/down keyboard key scrolling, or `touchmove` scrolling (which you would need to add a listener to as well).

For just the basic mousewheel event, you can use:

```
t!.addEventListener('wheel', handleScroll);
```

This should work, make sure to check for browser support and accessibility. And to add the listener to the `touchmove` event and up/down keys if needed.
You can review the arrow keys codes and proper event listener here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-detecting-the-pressed-arrow-key/

Comment: great answer. But can we specify the wheel direction and touchmove direction?

Comment: This is somewhat unreliable in some cases but you can get the direction with the `event.deltaY` (inside your callback function... `e.deltaY`).

You can read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event


As for the touchmove event, it's properties include the X and Y coordinates of the touch point's position relative to the viewport, page, and screen. Which you could then use to determine the direction of the user's swipe. You can read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events#interfaces